# I am confused about servletcontext

Tags: servlets

Context is a shared object and configure is different for every servlet. Why should I use servletConfig.getServletContext to get context? Seems like I should find where England is before I could locate Europe.

Answer (score 1):

The `ServletContext` object is a single object that represents the web application. Calling `getServletConfig().getServletContext()` from any Servlet in a running web application will always return the same `ServletContext` object.